# How to turn off the alarm on an iPhone XR without looking at the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

When the alarm rings on the iPhone, I have to pick up the phone and hit Stop on the screen. Pressing the volume buttons and the power button don't turn off the alarm but just snooze it.
Is there a way to stop the alarm while snooze is active?

Comment: Say, "Siri, turn off the alarm."  I think that works.  Try it.

Comment: @MacGuffin I think that makes things even more cumbersome

Comment: Can you double click the lock button?

Comment: @EzekielElin Yes I can but that doesn't work by default. Is there a way to activate that?